How to decide the project properly with own Oauth2 server and third-party oauth2 server
Currently I have 4 projects, Project A was react project act as front end, OAuth server project which can generate the JWT token, Resource Server project A (For example user-server, have controller like /login, /register and /userInfo.. which project A will be calling and for userInfo it need authentication, and resource server project B (for example payment-server) and have controller like /payByCredit. Currently what I have will be following:

Now my question is my ReactJS project will allow third party login, for example google, what I understanding right now is my ReactJS project need to add a new button said Login with Google and point to my user-server/login-with-google , and in my user-server, adding the new controller, in the config adding oauth2.client.registration.google.clientId and oauth2.client.registration.google.clientSecret etc...  and then userServer will return the access_token back to ReactJS. But the access_token was generate from google, if my ReactJS project using this token and try to access payByCredit from paymentServer, I believe it will failed, how to make that paymentServer also authorize and authenticate the access_token with google returned? Or something I understand wrong?

In a typical OIDC flow, your FE (ReactJS) communicates directly. with the authServer (1st or 3rd) party for the access token, then sends that to resource server (userServer), which validates the token, and issue the resource (information)
So, I'd do

(3rd Party OIDC) ReactJS -> Google Server and obtain GoogleAuthToken
(Token Exchange) ReactJS sends GoogleAuthToken to userServer,
2.1. (Backend Token process) userServer validates GoogleAuthToken and sends the correct information back to ReactJS (step 5.)
Continue with the returned information (step 6 onwards)

